# cudaMemcpy invalid argument: in simple vector example

Tags: memory, memory-management, cuda, gpu

The following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <math.h>


#define N 100
#define t_num 256

int main(){

     int vector_one_h[t_num], vector_one_g[t_num];

     cudaError_t err = cudaMalloc((void**)&vector_one_g, t_num * sizeof(int));
     printf("Cuda malloc vector swap one: %s \n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
     printf("Device Vector: %p \n:" , vector_one_g);

     for(int m = 0; m < t_num; m++){
             vector_one_h[m] = rand() % N;
     }

     err = cudaMemcpy(vector_one_g, vector_one_h, t_num * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
          printf("Cuda mem copy vector swap one: %s \n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
}
```

Will return:

```
Cuda malloc vector swap one: no error 
Device Vector: 0x7ffcf028eea0  
:Cuda mem copy vector swap one: invalid argument
```

So why is cudaMemcpy receiving an invalid argument?

From the documentation for `cudaMemcpy()` [here](http://horacio9573.no-ip.org/cuda/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g48efa06b81cc031b2aa6fdc2e9930741.html) I thought the problem may be that I need to give the second argument as the address, `&vector_one_h`, but placing that in the code returns the exact same error.

And also, while there are many posts about `cudaMemcpy` invalid arguments, I believe this is not a duplicate as most of the other questions have very complicated examples while this is a very simple and minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the first line to:

```
int vector_one_h[t_num], *vector_one_g;
```

BTW, prefixing an array name with an & has no effect. Array names are constant pointers by themselves, by the definition of C syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you edit your answer to explain why that's necessary? I'm surprised that I do not need to pre-allocate the size (I think I'm saying that right) of `vector_one_g` before copying.

Comment: malloc does the allocation. You only need to supply a pointer variable which will point to the newly allocated memory. In other words, cudaMalloc returns the address of the allocated memory in the pointer variable passed to it as the first argument.